# Refresh lightning component Opportunity page on Stage progress bar

Tags: lightning-aura-components, opportunity

I have a lightning component on the opportunity layout. I want it to refresh on stage change. Currently, it works when you change the stage using the edit button using the following code.

```
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:recordSaveSuccess" type="EVENT" />
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" />
```

[image]

When changing stage using the Sales Path component (pic below for reference), this event does not seem to be fired. Has anyone been able to subscribe to this component's events? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you update the opportunity stage using the Sales Path Component, it shows a toast after the update. You can handle that `showToast` event and then update your component accordingly.

```
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:showToast" type="EVENT" />
<aura:handler event="force:showToast" action="{!c.doInit}" />
```

Comment: This question has won the award as the [best answer from the 1st quarter of 2017](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-1st-quarter-of-2017).

Comment: Wow. This feels so great! Thanks Adrian. Also, thank you @SE_User, I hope you see this comment, I am not able to comment on the meta post.

Comment: Yeah, I lock it once voting closes so no one can place further votes, but that also prevents comments.

Comment: You're welcome, @SantanuHalder. (y) :)