# How to refresh whole page based on switching tab?

Tags: visualforce

In lightning experience page if I switch one tab to another tab whole page  has to refresh. how to do this? Please check Image for more Information.Lightning experience contains visualforce page.I need that switching tab functionality??

[image]

Comment: [Refresh lightning component Opportunity page on Stage progress bar](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/159036/29317) Will this help you?

Comment: @SE User thanks for reply..Itsnt Lightning component..I have one visualforce page & I placed this page in lightning experience page and i want that functionality in tat page